# Laplace Transform assistance

Tags: laplace-transform, solution-verification, partial-fractions, integral-transforms

Find the inverse laplace transform of: $\frac{25}{(s-1)^2(s^2+4)}$

$\frac{25}{(s-1)^2(s^2+4)}=\frac{A}{s-1}+\frac{B}{(s-1)^2}+\frac{C}{s^2 + 4}$
$$25=A(s^2+4)(s-1)+B(s^2+4)+C(s-1)^2$$
$\frac{25}{(s-1)^2(s^2+4)}=\frac{0}{s-1}+\frac{5}{(s-1)^2}+\frac{-15}{s^2 + 4}$

Maybe I don't know how to transform, but I got $5e^{\alpha t} -7.5 \sin(\alpha t)$ and this is apparently wrong. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$25=A(s^2+4)(s-1)+B(s^2+4)+(Cs+D)(s-1)^2$$ is correct. Therefore we have $$25=s^3(A+C)+s^2(-A+B-2C+D)+s(4A+C-2D)+(-4A+4B+D)$$ Now, $$A=0, -A+B+C=0,4A-2C=0, -4A+4B+C=25$$ which gives $$A=-2, C=2, D=-3, B=5$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on $(Cs+D)$?

Comment: Regarding to the method of partial fractions (as you can find it in integration) when you have $ax^2+bx+c$ in the denominator so you should assume something like `Ax+B` in its numerator.

Comment: I can't see a transform for such a numerator though?

Comment: @IanswereveryquestionIsee: I meant `C/(s^2+4)` should be `(Cs+D)/(s^2+4)`. Indeed, you have `s^2+4` so you should assume a term like `Cs+D` in the numerator.

Comment: I understood that part sorry, I meant that $Cs+D$ doesn't seem to be within any transforms for $\frac{Cs+D}{s^2+4}=\frac{2s-3}{s^2+4}$

Comment: @IanswereveryquestionIsee: `Cs/(s^+4)` is assotiated with `Ccos(2t)` and `D/(s^2+4)` is assotiated with `(D/2)sin(2t)`.